# React navigation createMaterialTopTabNavigator inside a screen

Tags: react-navigation

[React navigation createMaterialTopTabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/) shows a pretty cool setup at the top of their documentation page:

[image]

Notice that the top navigator stack seems to be inside a screen. There is a title at the top "Material Top Tabs" and we can go back to "Examples"

Funny enough, this setup is not given in any of the examples.

I would like to have the same setup and be able to navigate to a specific tab from another screen.

Could someone please share an example code for it?

What I currently have is a basic bottom tab navigation with a

```
<BottomTab.Screen
  name="Tabs"
  component={TabsNavigator}
/>
```

and then

```
function TabsNavigator() {
  const MyTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
  return (
    <MyTabs.Navigator
      <MyTabs.Screen name="Upcoming" component={TabsUpcomingScreen} />
      <MyTabs.Screen name="Past" component={TabsPastScreen} />
    </MyTabs.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Although this works when doing `navigation.navigate('Tabs', { screen: 'Upcoming' });`, I am missing the screen containing the tabs... or the "Tabs" screen (as in the example, it is the "Material Top Tabs" screen)

I could do something like this:

```
function TabsNavigator() {
  const TabsStack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <TabsStack.Navigator>
      <TabsStack.Screen name="Tabs" component={TabsScreen} options={{ headerTitle: 'Tabs' }} />
    </TabsStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function TabsScreen() {
  const MyTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
  return (
    <MyTabs.Navigator
      <MyTabs.Screen name="Upcoming" component={TabsUpcomingScreen} />
      <MyTabs.Screen name="Past" component={TabsPastScreen} />
    </MyTabs.Navigator>
  );
}
```

But then I am unable to navigate to a specific tab with `navigation.navigate('Tabs', { screen: 'Upcoming' });`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate to some tab inside of createMaterialTopTabNavigator.Instead of navigation.navigate('Tabs', { screen: 'Upcoming' }) use  navigation.jumpTo('Tabs', { name: 'Upcoming' });
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator#jumpto

Comment: I tried that, but if I first go to Tabs and select "Past", then go to another screen and click a button to navigation.jumpTo('Tabs', { name: 'Upcoming' }), it leads to the Tabs screen, but it stays on "Past" and doesn't go to "Upcoming"

Comment: BUT, strange enough, if I do `navigation?.navigate('Tabs');` followed by `navigation.jumpTo('Upcoming');`, then it works